# Safari's "Add image to iPhoto Library" creates new event each time

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, safari, iphoto

I recently discovered the "Add image to iPhoto Library" option in Safari's context menu. The problem is, despite the setting in iPhoto saying events are 1 per day, it create a new event for each photo.

Can I change this or am I SOL?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that behavior can be changed, but you can merge events in iPhoto. Select the events by command clicking the ones you want to merge, and click Merge on the toolbar.

(It might be that the images you are saving have an embedded date-stamp of their own that are separating the photos into events.)